# Selenium in Python - Running JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website that is mainly ran by javascript and it's giving me a huge headache because I don't know javascript.

This is what I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Users\kwright\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
driver.get('http://www.papowerswitch.com/shop-for-electricity/shop-for-your-home')
#zipcode = driver.find_element_by_id('edit-zipcode')
monthlyuse = driver.find_element_by_name('estimated-monthly-usage')
button = driver.find_element_by_id("edit-submit-residential-rate-search2")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-zipcode').value='18707'")
```

This works fine and it give me the value I need in the zip code section. The next part I'm having trouble with because the Id names aren't unique, but the name tag is, my problem is that I don't know the javascript function to get the element by the name tag and input the data I need.

I tried this and several variations of this and it didn't work.

```
driver.execute_script("driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('estimated-monthly-usage')).value='1000'")
```

can anyone help me out here and let me know what script I need to add to get that part of the form filled out? Thank you.

Edit:
Here is the HTML
    Monthly Usage

Comment: It might help if you show the html, but why can't you find the elements without javascript, just using Webdriver and Python?

Comment: It returns an error in python, the selenium driver in python won't send the keys, you have to do it through javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.findElement` is *Selenium* syntax, while inside `driver.execute_script` you need *JavaScript* syntax:

```
driver.execute_script("some javascript code comes here");
```

To find the right function, look at [document DOM object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp): just like `document.getElementById`, which you previously used, it has `document.getElementsByName()` function. Note that unlike ID, that can return 1 element only, there can be many elements with the same name, hence function returns them all as an array. So your statement becomes:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('estimated-monthly-usage')[0].value='1000'");
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you.