# how to scrape a value which is dynamically created by XHR and it dosn't show in selenium driver.page_source

Tags: python, selenium, xmlhttprequest

Trying to scrape a website which contains some dynamic data. These data could not be captured with **python selenium driver.page_source** even after adding lot of waits in it. But when I inspected with firebug, came to know that, these values were executed within browser console using referenced javascripts.

And, completely inspected the page source taken from selenium for these values and found no traces. All I can see only its id

But in actual browser, these values are present in it.

Comment: Can you give us the url and target.(what data you want to get)

Comment: i am so sorry, i cant give you that. But i hope  that i have explained about issue

Comment: i see this values are with the browser console

Comment: Trigger the scripts yourself then and grab the values after the scripts finish. `execute_script()` can be called to run js scripts from within the selenium webdriver.

Comment: @BoboDarph, first of all great answer, can you please show to how to trigger scripts with an example?,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518634/selenium-in-python-running-javascript https://dzone.com/articles/perform-actions-using-javascript-in-python-seleniu

Comment: Also do note that there are multiple other approaches to your problem. See resources [here](https://www.codementor.io/codementorteam/how-to-scrape-an-ajax-website-using-python-qw8fuitvi) or [here](http://toddhayton.com/2015/03/11/scraping-ajax-pages-with-python/). The gist of it being you will use some scrapper (like BeautifulSoup or scrappy) and cook the xhr request, send it, scrape the response data and then parse it if you can't simply trigger it to show up in your page_source by just running a javascript.

Comment: @BoboDarph, Thank you so much. your answers helped me a lot.